# Inconsistent file creation with batch

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop

I have this code which works perfectly on my desktop, creating the files quickly, but on my laptop it has a huge delay with the file creation. Is there something on my laptop causing this specifically? The CPU isn't weak as it's a i7-8550u with 16gb of RAM so what could be causing this issue?

Code:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

goto :start

:attackers
set i=0
for %%a in (Vigil Ela Lesion Mira Echo Caviera Valkyrie Frost Mute
            Smoke Castle Pulse Doc Rook Jager Bandit Tachanka Kapkan) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set operator[!i!]=%%a
)
set /a operator=%random%%%i+1
set operator=!operator[%operator%]!
copy /y NUL %operator% >NUL
exit /B

:start

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
call :attackers
echo !operator!
)
pause
```

Comment: Mabye Anti-Virus?

Comment: I am only running Windows Defender at this point. Disabling the active protection didn't change anything.